# Specify method implementation in impl for trait with shadowing method name

Tags: rust

Given the following trait + impl block, how can I call `std::vec::Vec`'s `get` method from the implementation for `MyMap`'s `get` method?

```
trait MyMap<K, V> {
    fn get(&self, key: &K) -> Option<&V>;
}

impl<V> MyMap<usize, V> for Vec<Option<V>> {
    fn get(&self, key: &usize) -> Option<&V> {
        match Vec::get(self, *key).expect("undersized map") {
            None => None,
            Some(v) => Some(&v),
        }
    }
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ff564e83b9439a0a622ab992dab7066)

I have tried:

- Hoping the compiler can infer from my types, as they are different:
  `self.get(*key).expect...`
  which makes the compiler resolve `MyMap`'s get and complain about the types being mismatched.
- Qualifying the type name: `Vec::get(self, *key).expect...`, which confusingly resolves `MyMap`'s get again, with the same errors as `self.get`
- Using [Fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name): `<Self as Vec>::get(self, *key).expect...` which makes the compiler complain about `get` not existing at all.
- Wrapping `Vec`'s `get` in a fn outside of the impl block, which does work but looks highly suspect and seems like the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` method for vectors isn't implemented directly on `Vec`. Instead, it's a function on a slice. So the easiest option is to first dereference your vector, yielding a slice, and then call `get()` on that slice:

```
impl<V> MyMap<usize, V> for Vec<Option<V>> {
    fn get(&self, key: &usize) -> Option<&V> {
        match (**self).get(*key).expect("undersized map") {
            None => None,
            Some(v) => Some(&v),
        }
    }
}
```

Since `self` has the type `&Vec<...>` we need to dereference twice to get a slice:

- By dereferencing once, we get a `Vec<Opiton<V>>`.
- Dereferencing again uses the `Deref` implementation on the vector and yields a `[Option<V>]`.

As a side note, the method body can be simplified using the `Option::as_ref()` method:

```
fn get(&self, key: &usize) -> Option<&V> {
    (**self).get(*key).expect("undersized map").as_ref()
}
```